# Two-way binding on a fileupload control with knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Not a problem having a fileupload control which has a custom binding to update observables, which subsequently result in the uploaded file being stored in an image uploads folder.

But how to do this in reverse so that when I edit an article I can retrieve the "file object" again to link to the fileupload control?  Because it's bound to the custom binding, the observables within cannot be set manually (I've tried to set the imageURL to a path I know exists, but the value does not stick and remains undefined.)

I believe I need to somehow set the main "file" observable to be a file object again, but I don't see how this can be done from my ajax call - how would I return the "file" as though it had just been selected in the fileupload control?

```
<input type="file" id="articleImage" data-bind="fileUpload: imageFile, fileObjectURL: imageObjectURL" />

ko.bindingHandlers.fileUpload = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                valueAccessor()(file);
            }
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var file = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if (bindings.fileObjectURL && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileObjectURL )) {
            var oldUrl = bindings.fileObjectURL ();
            if (oldUrl) {
                windowURL.revokeObjectURL(oldUrl);
            }
            bindings.fileObjectURL (file && windowURL.createObjectURL(file));
        }
   }
};
```

When I load data from file on editing an article and try and set the imageObjectURL to a string, it just ignores it and leaves it as null.  If I remove the second parameter from the data-bind html definition, I can set the observable directly.

The imageObjectURL is bound to an image control too, which works fine when I select an image, just not when I try and set it from file.

```
imageObjectURL("//path/to/image/image.jpg")
```

doesn't work - imageObjectURL stays "undefined" unless I remove it from the data-bind definition.

Comment: `bindings.imageObjectURL` is always false, because you don't have this binding. You should use `bindings.fileObjectURL` instead of it.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo in my question. The uploading bit works fine, I'm trying to get the system working when retrieving from the database.